# wordpress recommended requirements

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I want to install Wordpress on my server and i found at their site (https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) that the recommended requirement is php 7.2 (as a note it say its also support 5.4 but its discouraged, ) .
On my server i have ubuntu 16.04 and php 7.0. (sudo access).

My questions:

1) Will it work smoothly/at all or should i expect hard times to come with php 7.0.

2) I have few existing PHP projects (non-Wordpress), should i expect hard times to come if i upgrade or nothing was totally deprecated.

3) Does ubunto 16.04 have php 7.2 on the official repositories? (what i found on Google was mainly how to use ppa and I'm not sure if this info is up to date)

4) how can i check the above?

thanks

Comment: php 5.4 or higher. php 7.0 > php 5.4 . so, what is the problem?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan it does not say 5.4 or higher. its say 7.2 and that 5.4 is supported but discouraged. If you want to rephrase the question then it will ask  if there any reason why its not 7.0 and higher  ( commented after accepting the answer  ) -Edit: I see now way you said , i updated the question to be more clear)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1) Will it work smoothly/at all or should i expect hard times to come with php 7.0.

Will work fine on PHP 7.0 and according to benchmarks will run faster twice than php 5.6.

Here is some interesting information about Wordpress on various PHP's versions:

**[What’s New in PHP 7.2](https://kinsta.com/blog/php-7-2/)**

See the section: "*What Does PHP 7.2 Mean for WordPress Users?*"

It does cover 7.0 too, it's dated 4 March 2018

> 2) I have few existing PHP projects (non-Wordpress), should i expect hard times to come if i upgrade or nothing was totally deprecated.

Assuming your non-WP projects are written in PHP 5.6 you may have some issues.

Some parts of your code may need minor fixes.

See the official documentation: **[Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)**

> 3) Does ubunto 16.04 have php 7.2 on the official repositories? (what i found on Google was mainly how to use ppa and I'm not sure if this info is up to date)

Not that I'm aware of at the time of writing. If using ppa is an issue for you you then -standing at the informations above- you can run smooth on **7.0**